# Syntax error on token "/", Expression expected after this token

Tags: android, syntax-error, token

Why am I getting this error?
Syntax Error on token "/", Expression expected after this token.

```
 InputStream in = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.msgn);
 FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(media/audio/notifications/); // Error is in this line
                    byte[] buff = new byte[1024];
                    int read = 0;

                    try {
                       while ((read = in.read(buff)) > 0) {
                          out.write(buff, 0, read);
                       }
                    } finally {
                         in.close();

                         out.close();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mus put `media/audio/notifications/` in double-quote and pass them in a `File` constructor, since `FileOutputStream()` expects a `File` to pass in...

```
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("media/audio/notifications/"));
```

Answer (score 5):

he is expecting a string. You need double quote

```
"media/audio/notifications/"
```

Answer (score 0):

you forgot the quotes do this:

```
new FileOutputStream("media/audio/notifications/");
```